# django-rest-framework browsable API pre-fill ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to generate a link to `django-rest-framework` browsable API to add child object for the parent object. I want that `ForeignKey` field would be pre-filled with parent when user opens the page.

Is it possible to specify the initial field value through URL parameters? Or is there any general way how to pre-fill browsable API fields with different values for different instances?